# How to use a directive to pass default values in angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

I have created a custom component that has many input properties. However, one thing I have noticed when using this component is that many of the input properties are the same within the parent component.

An example usage looks like this:

```html
<yes-no
 controlName="isAwesome"
 labelKeyBase="MODULE.PAGE_X"
 validationKeyBase="VALIDATION.CUSTOM_X"
 someOtherProp="true"
></yes-no>
```

I have been using a library called transloco and noticed some functionality that would be very useful in this situation. Unfortunately, I have no idea how it would be implemented.

https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/docs/translation-in-the-template#utilizing-the-read-input

I'm wondering if there is a simplified example out there that demonstrates how to pass a value from a parent directive to a child component. Basically, my goal is to turn the above code into something like this:

```html
<ng-container *yesNoConfig="labelKeyBase: 'MODULE.PAGE_X'; validationKeyBase: 'VALIDATION.CUSTOM_X'">
 <yes-no controlName="isAwesome"></yes-no>
 <yes-no controlName="isClean"></yes-no>
 <yes-no controlName="isShort"></yes-no>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a directive that applies arbitrary attributes to all immediate children of the container:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[setAttributes]',
})
export class SetAttributesDirective {
  @Input('setAttributes') atts: { [key: string]: string } = {};

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const keys = Object.keys(this.atts);
    const viewRef = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    for (const node of viewRef.rootNodes) {
      if (typeof node.setAttribute !== 'function') continue;
      const el = node as HTMLElement;
      for (const key of keys) el.setAttribute(key, this.atts[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Not very typesafe since `viewRef.rootNodes` is type `any[]` but what can you do... I put somewhat of a typeguard anyway. The first entry is actually the `ng-container` itself, and nested templates / ng-containers will also not have a `setAttribute` function, throwing an error without the typeguard. Could definitely be improved, but at least you get the gist.

You'd use it like this:

```html
<ng-container *setAttributes="{ type: 'number', value: '5', min: '0', max: '10' }">
  <input />
  <input />
  <input />
  <input />
</ng-container>
```

Associated docs: https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1eyjlo?file=src/app/app.component.html

---

For your example you need to get the component instance from the DOM node. There is a function for that, although it's meant for debugging, not sure why it's not part of the regular API: https://angular.io/api/core/global/ngGetComponent

You'll have to tell tsc that the function exists, then you can set your component's properties:

```js
declare global {
  interface Window {
    ng: { getComponent: (el: Element) => { [key: string]: any } | null };
  }
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[setInputs]',
})
export class SetInputsDirective {
  @Input('setInputs') atts: { [key: string]: any } = {};

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const keys = Object.keys(this.atts);
    const viewRef = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    for (const node of viewRef.rootNodes) {
      if (!(node instanceof Element)) continue;
      const component = window.ng.getComponent(node);
      if (component === null) continue;
      for (const key of keys) component[key] = this.atts[key];
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ng-container *setInputs="{ labelKeyBase: 'MODULE.PAGE_X', validationKeyBase: 'VALIDATION.CUSTOM_X' }">
 <yes-no controlName="isAwesome"></yes-no>
 <yes-no controlName="isClean"></yes-no>
 <yes-no controlName="isShort"></yes-no>
</ng-container>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mbcw9o?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: This answer is very close to what I need. The example works great for a native html element like input, but not so much for a custom component. I can see that attribute getting set, but the value is never picked up by the custom component.

Comment: Yeah weird, seems like they only bind attributes when the component is first instantiated, and then just ignore any changes to the attribute after that... you'd have to somehow tell the template ref that these attributes need to be set before calling `viewContainer.createEmbeddedView` but I don't see an easy way to do that.

Comment: @ScottDietrich I updated my answer with how to retrieve the component instance from the DOM node. Not sure the implications of using this 'debugging' function in the application, I haven't looked into what the function is actually doing. I'm a bit worried it might be some sort of brute force search...

Comment: Thanks for adding this modification. One thing I keep asking myself is, how far do I want to go to save some boilerplate?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference I'm posting what I ultimately decided to do.

Chris Hamilton's answer got me very close to what I needed. However, in my example I needed to access to my Components so I could set their input properties. So instead of templateRef and viewContainer, I needed something more like `ContentChildren`. For some reason Angular (v12 for me) won't find the children within a structural directive. But if I changed it to an attribute directive it would work. Here is what I ended up with:

```
<ng-container [yesNoConfig]="{ labelKeyBase: 'MODULE.PAGE_X.' }">
  <div>
    <yes-no controlName="isAwesome"></yes-no>
  </div>
  <yes-no controlName="isClean"></yes-no>
</ng-container>
```

And...

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[yesNoConfig]',
})
export class YesNoConfigDirective implements AfterContentInit {
  private config: { [key: string]: string };

  @ContentChildren(YesNoComponent, { descendants: true }) children!: QueryList<YesNoComponent>;

  @Input() set yesNoConfig(config: { [key: string]: string }) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.children.forEach((child: YesNoComponent) => {
      child.labelKeyBase = this.config?.labelKeyBase;
      // TODO: Replace with loop/match of config properties
    });
  }
}
```

While I would prefer a solution that is more flexible and less tightly bound, this gets the job done for what I need.

Comment: I will also mention that I ran across another option:
https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/use-angular-directives-to-extend-components-that-you-dont-own#opt-in-directive

However, I did not like how the default properties are hidden within a separate directive.

Comment: One note on the implementation above, it is only run once. Therefore, I found out that components that start out hidden and are shown later on, will not receive these property values. There is a way to fix that, but at what performance cost... just to save some extra typing :)